# Why do CDNs allow arbitrary backend to be set, is it not a big security concern?

Tags: web-application, proxy, caching, cdn

I found most CDNs allow the user to claim *any* domains to be the backend, I wonder why they do this instead of verifying if the user owns the backend domain. If I have `myowndomain.com` and set the backend to be `facebook.com`, wouldn't it be an easier way to do attacks such as phishing? Of course, I still need to solve CORS, SOP, and Cookie related issues, but why do CDNs open the backend at the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... why do CDNs open the backend at the first place?

Anyone can already setup their own domain without a CDN so that it works as a proxy to another domain. A simple hosting service or VPS is needed for this and sometimes even a simple CNAME will do. Thus if a CDN allows this it essentially makes only available what is possible otherwise too.